# loading pdf content parsed from JSON in webView

Tags: ios, swift

I am loading pdf content from JSON and I would like to present it on webView control.

The pdf content is started by "%PDF-" and it is simply the same content if you open a pdf file in text editor.

I am using the following code to present the content in webView :

```
if let data:NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: pdfReport, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters) {
    self.webView.loadData(data, MIMEType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: NSURL())
                }
```

While "pdfReport" variable contains pdf content.

My code is not working, what's wrong on it?

Thanks

Comment: use in this place of UIDoumentationInteraction Controller

Comment: i successfully tried to show a local pdf with your options. So the problem is  the json content itself or the encoding.

Comment: The pdf content is in string format and I have to convert it to NSData in order to view it in webView. My problem with converting string to NSData.

Comment: in your sample code you are converting to NSData.

Comment: It is not converted correctly

Comment: I solve this issue by converting the pdf string that I got from JSON to Data using UTF8StringEncoding :  
  
`if let pdfData = pdfReport.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding){
                                self.webView.loadData(pdfData, MIMEType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: NSURL())
                            }`  
  
Thank you all for your responses